# Exe. path is not absolute (Trying to start a service I created)

Tags: services, autossh

I need to get an Ubuntu node to start an autossh tunnel to an SSH server when the node boots.

I have created a service with the following:

' ' ' '

**[Unit]**

Description=Autossh tunnel at boot

After=network-online.target

**[Service]**
Type=simple

User=root

ExecStart=/var/tmp/autossh.sh

Restart=on-failure

**[Install]**

WantedBy=multi-user.target

' ' ' '

The autossh.sh script found at **/var/tmp** contains the following:

**autossh zabbix-cli@123.123.123.123 -p 22**

The error I get when I run "sudo systemctl status autossh.service" is:
**/etc/systemd/system/autossh.service:8: Executable path is not absolute: autossh zabbix-cli@123.123.123.123 -p 22**

I have also tried to add the **"autossh zabbix-cli@123.123.123.123 -p 22"**
command directly after the ExecStart command in the service.

As far as I can read on other posts is that ExecStart needs the absolute path to the script it is supposed to run, which is what I have included.

I have also tried to add both **#!/bin/bash** to the start of the ExecStart command, and also at the top of the **autossh.sh** script, but I get the same error no matter what I do.

I have also tried to place the **autossh.sh** script at another location **(/home/username/)**

Comment: It should be obvious.  `autossh ....` isn't a absolute path. What it want is `/path/to/autossh ....`. Use `which autossh` to find the correct path to autossh.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working thanks to Soren A! The error was that I needed the absolute path, which is set when you install autossh (/usr/bin/autossh), then I had to put the parameters afterwards. I found an example here that I copied:
https://www.everythingcli.org/ssh-tunnelling-for-fun-and-profit-autossh/